# Would blood bags help a Red Court Infectee manage their hunger?

Tags: lore, dresden-files

Just someone reading up about the lore and templates in the system and wondering:

Is there anything on, if a Red Court infectee were to have access to and drink from blood bags, would that help alleviate/satiate their hunger and make it easier to control at all?

Or since it's not drank directly and freshly from a person, would it not work in this case?

Please answer with rules or lore from the Dresdenverse, not personal supposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, not at all.

> Anything short of freshly-spilled blood is less vital and, thus, less fulfilling; a fresh kill is like a three-course meal, while a bag from the blood bank is like an hors d'oeuvre - small and tasty, but ultimately leaving you hungry for the main course.
>
> **Blood Drinker**, YS188

If you're playing Core Dresden, your only option to help with the Discipline rolls to control your hunger is the Order of St. Giles. Otherwise you're really just relying on raw Discipline to not go hunger-crazed.

If you're playing Dresden Accelerated it's kind of worse - your Red Court mantle abilities are fueled by a sticky Hunger track, and the only way to clear it out is to set up an advantage and inflict a condition in melee; unless, again, you buy into the Order of St. Giles and are able to slowly clear the track over time.